# SQL wildcard matching excluding a specific pattern

Tags: sql, mysql

sorry about the question I am a newbie to sql. i am attempting to create a search query for our database and I was wondering how would you filter certain words from your query for example:

Here is the sample data (the name column): Jean, Jain, Joan, Jorn, Juan, John, Juin

Lets say that we are searching for the names that start with "J" and end with "n" but we don't want to include "John".

```
SELECT id, name
FROM tblusers
WHERE name LIKE 'j__n'
WHERE name NOT LIKE 'John'
```

Obviously the above will have an error, so I was wondering how do I correctly write the above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name
FROM tblusers
WHERE name LIKE 'j%n' 
AND name NOT LIKE 'John'
```

Comment: `AND`: +1. `SELECTR`: -1. Expanding for non-four-letter names: +1. I guess I have to click the up-arrow... :)

Comment: Great thanks Adam, I can't believe that is one combination i didn't try!

Comment: @Amadan: Thanks for the catch; I was typing that rater late at night for me ;)